# Which DBMS is best suited for a massive photo gallery using tags

Tags: database, rdbms, nosql

I'd like to implement a photo gallery from scratch, accessible through a web interface.
Here are some of its specs :

- around 300 simultaneous users
- more than 10 000 pictures
- each picture in the gallery is assigned some tags
- the user should be able to get all pictures corresponding to any combination of tags.

The idea is to use AJAX technology, so the web page dynamically reorganizes the pictures as soon as a query regarding the tags is entered. The system should therefore be highly-responsive.

Question of the day for you guys : **Which DBMS better suits this kind of project ?**

I'm currently hesitating between all of those :

- Relational DBMS (Oracle, MySQL)
- NoSQL DBMS

  - document (MongoDB)
  - key value stores (Redis)
  - wide column stores (Cassandra)

My particular concern is about the performance of the system. RDBMS such as Oracle might be too heavy for this kind of real-time application. Would NoSQL-wide-column db (such as Cassandra) be a better choice here ?

Many thanks !

Comment: When in doubt, use relational.

Comment: Well, I'm in doubt because I have no experience with NoSQL DBMS :) I just want to make sure that the use is right.

Answer (score 0):

Just use any DB you like mySQL, MongoDB - whatever you are good with.

Every record in your DB looks like this:

- id: 123456
- name: "a photo of new york"
- someotherfields: "with whatever content you might need"
- tags: "["city","new york", "central park", "usa"]

And use [Redis-Tagging](https://github.com/smrchy/redis-tagging) whenever you insert/edit/delete an item from your db.

Queries by tags (intersections **and** unions) are now really fast and your db stays dead simple.